# How to call public methood of myCustomAdapter in Main Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, realm

I have MainActivity and Adapter. When new instance of the adapter is created I create new realm. How can I close the realm in onDestroy methood?
Heres what i tryed:
MainActivity's onCreate:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ExpandableListView myELV;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = this.getSupportActionBar();
    myELV = findViewById(R.id.expandable_list_view);
    myAdapter adapter = new myAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    myELV.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The adapter:

```
public class myAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{
private Context context;
private Realm realm;


public myAdapter(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}
public void closeRealm(){
    realm.deleteAll();
    realm.close();
}
```

MainActivity's onDestroy:

```
    @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    ExpandableListAdapter adapter = myELV.getExpandableListAdapter();
    adapter.closeRealm();
}
```

But closeRealm() is unaccessable even tho it is public. And I want to know why?

Comment: And what didn't work about it?

Comment: Android Studio marks closeRealm() red, idicator that there is no such methood. I can acess the other adapter methoods, but this not.

Comment: `ExpandableListAdapter` is not of type  `myAdapter`. Btw are you sure you want to delete all data? :o

Comment: Yes! Thats it! It worked. Yes I will delete the realm while testing for now. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Echoing, @EpicPandaForce's answer, [ExpandableListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html) is the interface type. Your closeRealm() method isn't one of the methods in that interface. One thing you could do to fix this is create a a new interface that extends ExpandableListAdapter, and lists the signatures for the new public methods you want there. Then any class that implements your new interface can be swapped for any other class that implements your new interface.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using @EpicPandaForce's answer, I will post the change in the code if somebody is wondering in future:

```
    @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    myAdapter adapter =  (myAdapter) myELV.getExpandableListAdapter();
    adapter.closeRealm();
}
```